# How can I set up seamless navigation of vim and iterm2 splits?

Tags: iterm, macvim, vi

I am trying to map my C-h, C-j, C-k, C-l keys to be able to navigate vim (running in iterm2) splits but if there is no vim split to move to it should figure out that I want to jump to a different iterm2 window.

Pretty much this http://robots.thoughtbot.com/seamlessly-navigate-vim-and-tmux-splits but without having to run tmux (or at least without needing tmux to do the multiplexing)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is [this](https://github.com/zephod/vim-iterm2-navigator). I have not tried it, and it looks like it may not work in the latest iterm2.